# No sé como introducir datos adicionales a las tablas por defecto de wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-api

Tengo una tabla wp_user que es la tabla que por defecto genera al crear un proyecto en wordpress, la cosa es que no consigo meter datos adicionales al rellenar el formulario que me he creado con el plugin user registration, no se introducen en la base de datos que tengo en local con phpmyadmin. alguien me sugiere algo ? lo que tengo hasta ahora es este trozo de código en el archivo functions.php de mi tema activo, pero ni por asomo funciona.

```
add_action('user_register', 'mi_funcion_al_registrarse');

function mi_funcion_al_registrarse($user_id) {
    // Recuperar los datos del formulario de registro
    $localidad = $_POST['localidad'];
    $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];

    // Guardar los datos en la tabla wp_users
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'localidad', $localidad);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'provincia', $provincia);
}

// Initialize the theme.
call_user_func( 'Kadence\kadence' );
```

A ver si alguien puede brindarme algo de ayuda, gracias!

Comment: **users** y **usermeta** son dos cosas distintas. La primera usa datos "normales" y la segunda datos serializados.

Comment: wp_user guarda información de los usuarios pero los metadatos, como la dirección, edad, etc se guarda en la tabla wp_usersmeta, para verificar si se guarda bien solo llama a get_user_meta(), si obtiene datos es porque se ha guardado bien.

Answer (score 0):

Solo para ampliar la respuesta de los dos comentarios previos.

La función está bien, solo que los metadatos no se guardan en wp_users sino en wp_usermeta, verifica con `get_user_meta( $id_del_usuario )`.

Si aún así no se guarda, el problema podría venir de tu formulario, verifica si tu $_POST trae realmente los datos, aun así los campos localidad y provincia se deberían crear y mostrar vacíos si este fuera el caso.